# How to use iOS-Slide-Menu with the tab bar of navigation controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, side-menu

**Hi
I am using iOS-Slide-Menu, you can find it here**

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu.

> I am using tab bar with the navigation controllers, so I also want to
>   show the menu on the every navigation controllers of the tab bars
>   navigation controllers. It is showing but not working, please let me
>   know how to solve this.
>
> As we know that slide menu belongs to the main navigation controller,
>   but there are the multiple navigation controllers, where it is not
>   working.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you share some code?

Comment: @Koen, this slide navigation is the singleton, so the object can be made once, I have multiple navigations for the tab bar's view controller, So I want the menu in all the tab's view controller.